# Using Fourier integral formulae, show that $x=-\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\cos(sx)}{s^2}}ds$

Tags: integration

Using the formula for the cosine form of the Fourier integral representation,i.e

$f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{s=0}^{\infty}{\int_{t=0}^{\infty}f(t)\cos(sx)\cos(st)}dtds$

I let $f(t)=f(x) => f(t)=t$

I arrive at the point when I get

$f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{s=0}^{\infty}\cos(sx)[{\frac{t\sin(st)}{s}+\frac{\cos(st)}{s^2}]_0^{\infty}}ds$

I have trouble with how I can get the solution from this.

Edit: ANSWER: The key turns out to use laplace transforms to solve the integral. We let $f(t)=t=t*e^{-0t}$. Then while solving we arrive at a point when we get,

$f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{s=0}^{\infty}\cos(sx){\int_{t=0}^{\infty}t*e^{-0t}\cos(st)}dtds$

We put $st=p $ and that gives

$f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{s=0}^{\infty}\cos(sx){\int_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{p}{s}*e^{-0t}\cos(p)}\frac{dp}{s}ds$

which equals

$f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{cos(sx)}{s^2}{\int_{t=0}^{\infty}p*e^{-0\frac{p}{s}}\cos(p)}dpds$

Now using Laplace transforms we solve for

${\int_{t=0}^{\infty}p*e^{-0p}\cos(p)}dp$

which is the Laplace transform of $p*cos(p)$ at $z=0$ and comes out to be $-1$

Hence the solution.

Comment: as an suggestion, try to change the multiplication to sum

Comment: It is the same result eventually. It doesn't change the limits anyhow. That is what is causing the problem.

Comment: Are you sure about your formula? The integral $\int_0^{+\infty}\cos(sx)/s^2\,ds$ is clearly divergent due to the singularity at $s=0$.